# HTMLTestRunner is not working

Tags: html, python-3.x, python-unittest

I'm trying to generate an HTML report from my Unittests of Python3.6. I'm using the [HTMLTestRunner](https://github.com/dash0002/HTMLTestRunner) library.

Here are my unit tests:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import unittest
import boto3
import warnings
import HTMLTestRunner

class SecurityGroupTest(unittest.TestCase):


    def setUp(self):
        session = boto3.Session(profile_name='default')
        self.ec2_clt = session.client('ec2')

    def test_delete_03(self):
        response = self.ec2_clt.describe_security_groups()
        self.assertEqual(len(response['SecurityGroups']), 0)


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        HTMLTestRunner.main()
```

When I run the tests, nothing is generated. What am I missing here?

Comment: `if __name__ == "__main__"` is indented incorrectly and will never be run

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you solved? Only the indent was wrong?

Comment: @fabio no ... unfortunately

Comment: This works on python 3.6.4 https://pypi.org/project/html-testRunner/